# android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren

Tags: java, android, crash, android-framelayout

I am Currently getting tons of crashes in Fabric regarding many different instances of the same crash. I.E **FrameLayout.java line 275**, **FrameLayout.java line 405**, **FrameLayout.java line 531**. There is no clear indication as to what is happening when this crash happens. There is especially no line reference to any of my code. Has anyone experienced anything like this, does anyone know what is causing this, and does anyone know a solution to the problem? Thank you!

```
    **FrameLayout.java line 531
    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren**

    Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke 
    virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object 
    reference
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:275)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
           at 
   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
           at 
    android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
          at 
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:954)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19039)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5935)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2711)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2426)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1569)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7296)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:930)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:705)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:640)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:916)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Comment: Are you using dexguard/proguard ? and do you have any missing stack trace on your dashboard ?

Comment: I am also facing.
Have you found any solution?

Comment: maybe share your xml file where you have the framelayout. the exception seems to relate to whatever is inside that framelayout

Comment: I'm facing the same issue now. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think error is in your layout.
2. These type of error happens when you are using wrong id
3. Check all your views id and match them in java file(try renaming them)

Comment: Not related to xml layout

Comment: Share your layout and code

Comment: Have checked all layouts.
Found error in fast scrolling implementation of recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

I faced an error similar to this when I migrated to androidX. It was showing an error related to setting visibility on null object reference and  pointed it to layout.In my case, the layout was used for a custom alert dialog. When I looked into the code there was no error but the alert dialog implementation was changed to androidx.appcompat.app . I changed that back to the previous one ,then it was working. Actually the project was using legacy code, then I had to refactor it :D